# clear cookies in PHP which created by CGI

Tags: php, cgi

I have created Cookie in CGI page and tried to clear in PHP page.

CGI source:

```
Set-Cookie: cookieName="value"; path=/;\n
```

PHP source:

```
setcookie ("cookieName", "", time() - 3600);
unset($_COOKIE['cookieName']);
```

Have an idea? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the name of your cookie is value , as shown in your code

setcookie ("value", "", time() - 3600);
unset($_COOKIE['value']);

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In CGI, every time get cookies from the following

```
$env{'CookieName'}
```

To clear in PHP, I tried the following coding

```
// unset cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

Thanks to all